# Dtls handshake failed with Alert after ServerHelloDone

Tags: c++, openssl, handshake, dtls

I'm implementing DTLS client for my windows app using openssl.
I run 'openssl s_server' on a linux machine for testing as following

*openssl s_server -key key.pem -cert cert.pem -dtls1 -accept 44330 -debug -state*

After ServerHelloDone, there's an Alert in wireshark from client to server.

Logs from client:

> SSL_CB_EXIT SSL_connect: SSLv3 read server hello A
>
> SSL_CB_LOOP SSL_connect: SSLv3 read server hello A
>
> SSL_CB_LOOP SSL_connect: SSLv3 read server certificate A
>
> SSL_CB_EXIT SSL_connect: SSLv3 read server key exchange A
>
> SSL_CB_ALERT write: fatal: internal error
>
> SSL_CB_EXIT SSL_connect: error

Logs from server:

> SSL_accept:SSLv3 write key exchange A
>
> SSL_accept:SSLv3 write server done A
>
> SSL_accept:SSLv3 flush data
>
> SSL3 alert read:fatal:internal error
>
> SSL_accept:failed in SSLv3 read client certificate A
>
> ERROR
>
> 140586308581032:error:14102438:SSL routines:DTLS1_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert internal error:d1_pkt.c:1173:SSL alert number 80
>
> shutting down SSL

It seems client can't send its data after ServerHelloDone.
Does anyone know what the problem is really about?

Comment: What is the exact version of open ssl you are using on the client side.  Basically it's a "internal error" reported on line 1173 in code file d1_pkt.c in function dtls1_read_bytes.   At a guess, reordered packets and/or fragmented packets. Wireshark the on the server side and on the client side and confirm the packets come in the same order and are not fragmented or "modified" in any way.

Comment: It's 1.0.2k on client and 1.0.1g on server and wireshark on client show no fragmentation. But when I upgrade the version on server to 1.0.2k then wireshark on client show fragmented messages from server. So should I fallback the version on client, or is there any other solution?

Comment: Hi, the version mismatch seems to be the cause. After use 1.0.2k for both sides and use Dtlsv1.2 the handshake is done successfully. Previously I used Dtlsv1 with 1.0.2k on client and 1.0.1g on server, don't know why is didn't work. Thanks for your hint @ShanePowell